# Migrating a small web application for smartphones by creating narrow HTML pages?

Tags: html, web-applications, iphone, migration, android

I have a small web site offering a couple of functionalities, but it was not designed to operate with smartphones then. I don't have experience with smartphone application development (and this might be over-engineering too), but I was wondering if I could use another method.

From [here](http://labs.thesedays.com/blog/2010/07/16/10-tips-for-designing-mobile-websites/), I notice that all smartphone screen support 320px width when held vertically. Could I develop HTML pages where content is squeezed properly within 320px and extended over 480px (and more)? Would this be displayed properly on smart phones? Should I save some space for scrolling bars?

Or should I invest time learning to use a proper CSS framework for smartphones? If yes, does anyone have recommendation to make? Ideally, I would like to just take a copy of my pages and reorganize them for smartphones to keep things simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technique you're looking for is called `responsive design`, utilizing CSS3, this approach allows the content layout and text sizing to change according to the user's browser window size or the screen resolution of their chosen device.

Here are a few resources/links/ideas:-

- [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) is a great example of responsive design in action
- [SpeckyBoy magazine](http://speckyboy.com/2011/11/17/15-responsive-css-frameworks-worth-considering/) has a great roundup of CSS frameworks to look through, [LESS](http://lessframework.com/) is particularly good IMHO.
- [SmashingMagazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) has a great introduction to responsive design.